# Knex.js Incorrect integer value: '[object Object]' for column 'user_id' at row 1

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js

I'm currently working on a project in express and I'm using knex.js to handle migrations and queries.

I'm still trying to grasp the concept of promises and how I can run multiple queries with knex.

I have the following code:

```
this.addUnit = function(unit_prefixV, unit_nameV, unit_descriptionV, profile_id) {
    return knex.insert({ 'unit_prefix':unit_prefixV, 'unit_name':unit_nameV, 'unit_description':unit_descriptionV }).into('units')
    .then(function(unit) {
        return knex('users').where({ 'google_id':profile_id }).select('id')
        .then(function(uid) {
            return knex.insert({ 'unit_id':unit, 'user_id':uid }).into('users_units');
        });
    });
}
```

however I am returned with the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect integer value: '[object Object]' for column 'user_id' at row 1
```

In my `routes` file I have the following post method:

```
app.post('/dashboard/unit/add', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
        let postErrors = []
        if (req.body.unit_name.trim() == "") {
            postErrors.push('Unit name cannot be empty.')
        }

        if (req.body.unit_prefix.trim() == "") {
            postErrors.push('Unit prefix cannot be empty.')
        }

        if (req.body.unit_description.trim() == "") {
            postErrors.push('Unit description cannot be empty.')
        }

        if (postErrors.length > 0) {
            res.render('addUnit', { errors: postErrors, user: req.user })
        } else {
            unitModel.addUnit(req.body.unit_prefix.trim(), req.body.unit_name.trim(), req.body.unit_description.trim(), req.session.passport.user.id).then(function(unit) {
                res.redirect('/dashboard')
            })
        }
    })
```

For reference my users table consists of:

- id
- google_id

my users_units table consists of:

- user_id
- unit_id

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(uid))`?

Comment: When I do `console.log(JSON.stringify(uid))` I get `[{"id":1}]`

Comment: I guess this is desired behavior : It returns an array of result objects. Here there's one result which is an object containing only an id

Comment: Therefore, I suggest to rename `uid` to `results` and then do `const uid = results[0].id`

Comment: From the knex docs for select: 'The response of a select call will resolve with an array of objects selected from the database.' That's exactly what it's doing and you are trying to pass that array as an id.

Comment: That fixed it! thank you :)

Comment: @MattKent you could also consider using `first()` if you know you're just getting one result: http://knexjs.org/#Builder-first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unit` is an object, you'll have to access the properties (unit_id) - depending on your db you may also have to do something special to get the result inserted object (instead of just the number of rows). The error you are getting is because knex select resolves an array. You can either do `first` or access the first element of the array.